# How to git clone a LFS repo through python?

Tags: python, git, git-lfs

I need to clone a repo that uses LFS through code.

I tried using `GitPython` as follows:

```
from git.repo.base import Repo
Repo.clone_from("https://foo.bar/baz", "./foo/bar/")
```

However, this only downloads a pointer to the LFS files but does not actually download them.

Comment: Git-LFS isn't Git: you need the LFS wrappers, which you get by installing LFS and using `git lfs clone` instead of `git clone`. How to do that from the Python `git` package will depend on your Python `git` package (if it's capable of doing that at all).

Comment: You don't need to use `git lfs clone` and shouldn't.  You can just run `git lfs install` once after installing Git LFS and then use the regular `git clone`.

Answer (score 2):

As of right now, git LFS is implemented in Go and maintained by GitHub (a maintainer already commented on your question), purely for use [as a binary, aka git CLI extension](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/tree/ed38002ac5aaf810daab150f2d9aa1359629b28b#limitations):

> However, we do not maintain a stable Go language API or ABI, as Git LFS is intended to be used solely as a compiled binary utility. Please do not import the `git-lfs` module into other Go code and do not rely on it as a source code dependency.

So even if you wrote Go, no library is available. No other meaningful implementations seem to exist either, although [some are on their way](https://github.com/Byron/gitoxide/tree/af843f8fe6dd91dcc7df3c5805d181af2ea86570/gix-lfs). There is [`git-lfs-fetch`](https://github.com/liberapay/git-lfs-fetch.py), a pure Python implementation of *parts* of git LFS, but it is abandoned.

A popular, general purpose git library is [`libgit2`](https://libgit2.org/), making much of git available as a C library. There is a Python library with bindings to it, [`pygit2`](https://www.pygit2.org/). But much like its [underlying library](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/search/lfs), `pygit2` has [makes no mention of supporting lfs](https://www.pygit2.org/search.html?q=lfs&check_keywords=yes&area=default). Using LFS from `libgit2` directly is [not straightforward](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/6565) in itself anyway.

Next to bindings, one might like to use a native (git) reimplementation. For Python, [Dulwich](https://www.dulwich.io/docs/) is such a project. As of today, it does not support LFS. There is only [little code already implemented towards supporting LFS](https://github.com/jelmer/dulwich/blob/879fe6a17b694df8d6f4f91cdbf808a59d6a105d/dulwich/lfs.py), and the corresponding [tracking issue](https://github.com/jelmer/dulwich/issues/748) is as quiet as can be. I wouldn't bet on this feature being available anytime soon, as it is not trivial (original git LFS is 40k SLOC Go).

There seems to be no alternative to shelling out directly, as mentioned in the comments to your question already. You will need to [install git LFS](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/tree/ed38002ac5aaf810daab150f2d9aa1359629b28b#installing) on your system, outside of Python, and then shell out to it via [Python's `subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) (or its [`async` alternative](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html)):

```py
import subprocess

result = subprocess.run(["git", "lfs", "ls-files"])
print(result)
```

This sadly means one has to perform error handling by handling return codes and `stderr` output, etc. An upside is that there's zero ambiguity: you're using *the* git LFS, so anything that git LFS can do, your solution will be compatible with. There's no opportunity for Python libraries to get in the way to introduce additional bugs or lack features available in upstream git LFS. Only the system's `git-lfs` version matters.